Live Reload in docker-compose project für Ionic app not working
I am trying to build an ionic project that uses node.js backend, each service packed into a container providing a microservice architecture.
For the node.js backend live reload is working, ionic serve on the other hand does not recognize changes in the code made locally that should be mounted into the container using a volume.
This is my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ./backend/user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./backend/user-service:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_USERNAME: admin
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: admin-dev
      DATABASE_NAME: user-db
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin-dev
      POSTGRES_DB: user-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  # standard port for PostgreSQL
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  # persistent saving of data for postgres

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Dockerfile in Frontend-Folder
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - app-network  # shared network for all services
    depends_on:
      - user-service  # Frontend starts after user-service


networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge  # standard network mode (all services communicate here)

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Here is my Dockerfile for the frontend service:
# Use an image with an up-to-date version of node
FROM node:18.20.0

# Install the ionic and angular CLI globally
RUN npm install -g @ionic/cli @angular/cli

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all code into the working dir
COPY . /app

# Open standard port for Ionic
EXPOSE 8100

# Start the Ionic server and set host flag to open it externally
CMD ["ionic", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8100", "--disableHostCheck", "--watch", "--poll"]

Starting the application works fine, as the frontend is built and I can access it via the browser on the defined port.
However, changes made in the home.html are not reflected in the container and the process does not compile and reload the page.
Running the front locally works fine and changes are immediately reloaded on browser refresh.
What do I need to change?
EDIT: I also tried using the beevelop Image for dockerized Ionic development, however when starting the container using this image I get the notification that the Angular CLI expects a node version of >18.20 and I could not make it work to update it accordingly when building the container.

Can you use plain Node without Docker for this setup?  It typically works well to run the backend services and databases in containers, while using a non-container Node for developing the frontend, and this can work even if you'll eventually deploy the frontend in a container.

Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, if I run the frontend locally - outside a container - it works fine, even though as of now I did not connect the frontend to speak with the API (should not pose a problem I think). So you suggest to develop the frontend locally and as soon as I put it into production I should deploy it in the container?

The frontend ultimately runs in the end user's browser, so it can't use any Docker networking features (see for example "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend).  It's a good idea to run local integration tests using your full container stack, without volumes: that overwrite the code built into the images.
